# Could people around the world demand Lumens XLM?

Tags: xlm, lumens

I am developing a site based on a premise that has not yet been fulfilled. My idea is to create a website where people can share the different ways to earn Lumens XLM, thereby helping to flourish the economy of individuals based on the free trade of financial experiences. The question is, does this make sense to you? I want to validate this idea with as many perspectives as possible, and it would greatly help me if you could leave a comment in the waitlist section if you find the idea interesting.

Here is the link: https://earnlumens.com/

Have an excellent day.